# Migrate accessing source fields by name instead of by selector?

Tags: migrations

I'm working on the MongoDB source plugin and I'm able to do the migration, but I have to make strange compromises. When defining the source fields, I have to set name the same as selector, like this.

```yaml
fields:
  -
    name: _id
    label: 'Unique ID'
    selector: _id
```

That works, but if I decide to change field name and keep selector, the migration fails.

```yaml
fields:
  -
    name: node_id
    label: 'Unique ID'
    selector: _id
```

I get this error.

> 'node_id' is defined as a source ID but has no value.

Why is that? Why is the source array accessed by name instead of by selector?

Comment: This highly depends on the source plugin implementation. For instance, in `migrate_plus`'s JSON source, the `selector` is xpath to the data and `name` is the shorthand. However, for `migrage_source_csv`, the `name` must be the heading value. It also has `label` but no `selector`. So you'll have to dig into the source's implementation to see what properties it needs and what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selectors are handled by data processor plugins. Initially I tried to use iterator object provided by MongoDB collection object. That works, but selectors are not supported.
Then I saw how custom data processor is made in Migrate plus module, for parsing json and made one based on that. Basically I'm using collection iterator to get full json and then my custom data processor works with that json the similar way as Migrate Plus json data processor does.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the name of source fields, but you must not change the name of source fields used as source IDs.

```
source:
  fields:
    -
      name: _id
      label: 'Unique ID'
      selector: _id
  ids:
    _id:   <-- this is the problem, you can not rename source fields used here
      type: integer
```

On the first migration the module creates a mapping table `migration_map_MIGRATION_ID` for each remote source row <=> local entity. After that, you no longer can change the name of source fields used as source IDs.

The only way around this is a complete rollback, then manually deleting those migration tables (including table `migration_message_MIGRATION_ID` ) and then you can make a fresh start.

Comment: @hundri thanks for explaining this. However source parameter is not working at all, not even for other fields. From what Joseph said and from other source I think that source plugin it self has to implement that functionality. But problem is I can find and instructions/tutorial on how to do that.